# Interconnection between two Convolutional Layers

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a question regarding interconnection between two convolutional layers in CNN. for example suppose I have architecture like this:

input: 28 x 28

conv1: 3 x 3 filter, no. of filters : 16

conv2: 3 x 3 filter, no. of filters : 32

after conv1 we get output as 16 x 28 x 28 assuming dimension of image is not reduced. So we have 16 feature maps. In the next layer each feature map is connected to next layer means if we consider each feature map(28 x 28) as a neuron then each neuron will be connected to all 32 filters means total 
(3 x 3 x 16) x 32 parameters. How these two layers are stacked or interconnected? In the case of Artificial Neural Network we have weights between two layers. Is there something like this in CNN also? How the output of one convolutional layer is fed to the next convolutional layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of parameters of a convolutional layer with `n` filters of size `k×k` which comes after `f` feature maps is

```
n ⋅ (f ⋅ k ⋅ k + 1)
```

where the `+1` comes from the bias.

Hence each of the `f` filters is not of shape `k×k×1` but of shape `k×k×f`.

> How the output of one convolutional layer is fed to the next convolutional layer?

Just like the input is fed to the first convolutional layer. There is no difference (except the number of feature maps).

### Convolution on one input feature map

[image]

Image source: https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic

See also: [another animation](https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/more_images/Convolution_schematic.gif)

### Multiple input feature maps

It works the same:

- The filter has the same depth as the input. Before it was 1, now it is more.
- You still slide the filter over all (x, y) positions. For each position, it gives one output.

### Your example

- First conv layer: 160 = 16*(3*3+1)
- Second conv layer: 4640 = 32*(16*3*3+1)

Comment: Actually first convolutional layer have only one input image. After first convolutional layer we have output of 16 images (feature maps), right? So how will the second convolutional layer take input these 16 images?

Comment: How will the second convolutional layer take input these 16 images and output 32 images (feature maps)? So each filter in 2nd convolutional layer has 16 inputs?

Comment: This is how a convolutional filter works with one input feature map: https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/more_images/Convolution_schematic.gif - if you have multiple input feature maps, the filter just gets a depth dimension. No big change.

Comment: see also: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/Art/kernel_convolution.jpg